If Tap is reset after switching menu screens while using avalondock LayoutPanel, how can I disable the reset? C#
I can't show you the entire code.
The program I'm developing has some buttons on the UI,
This is a program that switches the screen under the UI to another screen when you press a button.
In the first screen, avaloneDock uses LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup. If you select another tab in the LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup and press the button in the UI above to switch to another screen and return to the original screen, tapping it will return you to the original default tab. (If SelectedContentIndex is 3, tapping will return to the original screen. (Phenomenon where it is reset to 0 when you return)
Can this phenomenon be fixed?
Thank you.
<ad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                        <ad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <ad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Number1">
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding num1}"/>
                            </ad:LayoutAnchorable>
                            <ad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Number2" >
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding num2}"/>
                            </ad:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </ad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    </ad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup >


As it is, your question is very hard to understand. Even if you cannot (and should not!) post your entire code, you should provide a [mre] showing the problem. Then it will probably become more clear what you mean e.g. by "switch the screen"
